# Remove items from list that exist in another list

Tags: c#, asp.net

Both the following lists contain a QuoteID field. What is the best way to eliminate items from the currentQuotes list that have a QuoteID that exists in the quoteData list? Thanks.

```
  //Establish - Instantiate lists
  IList<QuotePaneView> currentQuotes = new List<QuotePaneView>();
  IList<Quote> quoteData = new List<Quote>();

  //Fill lists
  currentQuotes =  theQuotePaneService.GetAllQuotePanelStuff();
  quoteData =  theQuoteDataService.GetAllQuoteData();
```

Comment: What have you tried? And what does "best" mean in your situation? (best is relative)

Answer (score 2):

A simple piece of Linq can help here:

Consider the following:

```
        var list1 = new List<int>();

        list1.Add(1);
        list1.Add(3);
        list1.Add(5);

        var list2 = new List<int>();

        list2.Add(1);
        list2.Add(2);
        list2.Add(3);

        var diff = list1.Except(list2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) to get the set difference based on the ID. Then you only have to join the result(the unique ID's that are not in quoteData) to the `currentQuotes` list.

```
var notInQuoteData = currentQuotes.Select(q => q.QuoteID).Except(quoteData.Select(q => q.QuoteID));
var result = (from qUnique in notInQuoteData 
             join q in currentQuotes on qUnique equals q.QuoteID
             select q).ToList();
```